# How to find out the consecutive word in a sentence using R code

Tags: regex, r

How to find out the consecutive word in a sentence using R code.

For Example:

There is a sentence like mentioned below  which is the output of the following

```
sentence <- text[grep("Guarantee of",text)]
```

"You are requested to submit the Performance Guarantee of Rs.13,863.00/-( Rupees thirteen thousand and eight sixty three)"

Now I need to get the consecutive word of **"Guarantee of"** which is **"Rs.13,863.00/-"**

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence <- 'You are requested to submit the Performance Guarantee of Rs.13,863.00/-( Rupees thirteen thousand and eight sixty three)';
sub('.*Guarantee\\s+of\\s+([a-zA-Z0-9,._/-]+).*','\\1',sentence);
## [1] "Rs.13,863.00/-"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gsub('.*Guarantee of\\s*|\\(.*', '', str1)
[1] "Rs.13,863.00/-"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, '(?:Rs.)[^(]+')
#[1] "Rs.13,863.00/-"
```

#### data

```
  str1 <- "You are requested to submit the Performance Guarantee of Rs.13,863.00/-( Rupees thirteen thousand and eight sixty three)"
```